# Strange behaviour of Text widget which is filled with multiple space characters on OS X

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am developing an app which is similar to Notepad, using Python Tkinter to create GUI. Text widget is acting as an area for entering text.
The strange thing that I noticed is that when I enter multiple space characters in a row, let's say 20, clicking somewhere between e.g. 16 and 17 space character results in placing the cursor (as well as index attribute of the widget) between the 1st and the 2nd space characters, not near the area where I click (please refer to links to screenshots below).

[1. Proof that a row of space characters is entered in the Text widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7yFe.png)

[2. Cursor is placed after the 1st character of the line after clicking between further characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed0BE.png)

I confirmed to myself that this is not the standard behaviour of OS X by opening TextEdit app and trying the same there - everything worked fine - the cursor was placed between the spaces where I click (not at the beginning of the line).

Also, when inserting any other characters than spaces (e.g. dots, letters, etc) in my app's Text widget, everything also works fine.

When running the exact same code on Windows, Text widget behaves as expected - the cursor appears right between the two space characters that were the nearest to the place I click.

Does anyone know how to 'switch this off' when running on OS X?
Thanks in advance!

Attaching my code here:

```
from Tkinter import *

# Functions
def quitApplication():
    '''Quit application the right way'''
    mainWindow.destroy()

def createNewEmptyArea(width, height):
    '''Create area of empty spaces'''
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            mainTextField.insert(END, " ")
        mainTextField.insert(END, "\n")

# Create main window
mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', quitApplication)

# Main panel for text widget:
mainPanel = Frame(mainWindow, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
mainPanel.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Text
mainTextField = Text(mainPanel, wrap=NONE)
mainTextField.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Fill text widget with 100 rows of space characters with 100 spaces characters in each row
createNewEmptyArea(100, 100)

# Run (loop) main window
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible to have access to the app, so that we can try it also?

Comment: Anyway, I've just noticed that this strange behaviour also occurs with my IDLE's editor (I'm on a OS X), even though, apparently from what you said, it doesn't with your IDLE's editor.

Comment: @nbro I've attached the source code that I run to the main post.
I haven't tried the IDLE editor (btw, isn't it based on Tkinter itself?), I performed the test on TextEdit app (which is default on OS X, I suppose) and there was no problem there.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, I think this is a problem you can't avoid because of the reasons I mentioned before, but it may also be possible to fix it.

Comment: Sorry I understood you tested it with your IDLE, but you checked the presence of this behaviour in another editor. I'm afraid is really due to tkinter...